# The integral of the log spectral density for a infinite MA process.

Tags: time-series, stationary-processes, discrete-time

Let us consider a MA($\infty$) process:

$y_t= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_j \varepsilon_{t-j}  $

where

$ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_j^2 < \infty  \>\>\>\>\>\> $   (1)

Given $f(\lambda)$ as the spectral density of the process $y_t$, does the square summabilty condition (1) imply that the following equality $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \log f(\lambda) d \lambda =0   $ holds ?

Comment: Let me also precise, is it a consequence of the Kolmogorov's formula (see Theorem 5.8.1 in Brockwell and Davids (1986) Time Series: theory and methods, second edition Springer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a consequence of Theorem 5.81 in Brockwell and Davids (1986) "Time Series: theory and methods, second edition Springer", the relation $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \log f(\lambda) d \lambda = =0 $ holds for any stationary process $y_t$. In particular, if $y_t$ is long memory such that $ f(\lambda_c) = \infty$ for some $ \lambda_c \in [-\pi, \pi]$, then the previous relation is still true, because the theorem allows for a spectral density defined in $[-\pi, \pi]$ except for a set of zero Lebesgue measure.